# need to click on a button with selenium

Tags: selenium

I need to click on a button using selenium (java server) - the button only has a type and no id/value.  Any helpful suggestions would be most welcome

```
<button type="submit">Enter</button>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following worked for me:

```
selenium.click("//button[@type='submit']"
```

Comment: There you are using XPath to locate the element to click on. Alternative is CSS. This XPath is quite generic, if there are now two buttons on your site, the selector will find both. Which one will be clicked depends on the implementation of the client, probably the first button found. Something to keep in mind.

Answer (score 1):

Another option is //button[contains(text(),'Enter')], though this would break if you have localized sites..